# Best strategy for staging and production environments in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Currently, I am running a nodejs application with AWS Beanstalk as well as AWS CodeDeploy and CodeBuild. Also, I push to a github repository to start the automation of my CodeDeploy pipeline.

What is the best / cleanest strategy to have a staging environment be pushed to first, and if all tests are ok, approve to push it to production?

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by "Strategy"? you seem to already known some tools and you already known you want a staging and a production environment. What do you want to know more?

Comment: I am unsure of the process to easily integrate both a staging and production environment with tools I use. i.e Is there an easy way to hit a "confirm" button or something similar after doing testing in the staging environment to push it to production or something similar

Comment: did you find anything in AWS's documentation for all the products you listed? how about github?

Comment: I found some vague language. Most articles / support essentially just created a whole new pipeline and a seperate app. That is cureently why im asking if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Do you have separate prod and dev accounts?

Comment: Do you mean separate AWS accounts? Currently, I do not, is there a way to manage multiple AWS accounts from 1 master account?

Answer (score 3):

This is something that AWS recommend having multiple cross accounts deployment separating Dev and Tools account. Detailed blog is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/).

[image]

You can add a Manual Approval action as last action in DeployToTest stage to guardrail a production deployment.

[image]